# Java netbeans issue

Tags: java, netbeans, java.util.scanner

Please help me with this netbeans assignment code. I have been working on it for a few hours, and I don’t understand it.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks mr.polywhirl, but that isn’t correct for me somehow

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using raw user input for now, and just focus on creating a reusable method that does your calculation internally. There is no reason to cast to a float, because all the values should be floating-point values.

The `calc` method handles the calculation that you have copy-pasted three times.

```java
public class CalculateHalfLife {
    public static double calc(double amount, double halfLife, double hours) {
        return amount / (Math.pow(2, (hours / halfLife)));
    }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        double amount = 100; // mg of caffeine
        double halfLife = 6; // hours
         
        double[] allHours = { 6, 12, 24 };
         
        for (double hours : allHours) {
            double output = calc(amount, halfLife, hours);
            System.out.printf("After %.0f hours: %.2f mg\n", hours, output);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to to support user input, you should prompt the user to enter input:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalculateHalfLife {
    private static double amount = 100; // mg of caffeine
    private static double halfLife = 6; // hours
    private static double[] allHours = { 6, 12, 24 };
    
    public static double calc(double amount, double halfLife, double hours) {
        return amount / (Math.pow(2, (hours / halfLife)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter an amount: ");
        float amount = sc.nextFloat();
        System.out.println();
        
        for (double hours : allHours) {
            double output = calc(amount, halfLife, hours);
            System.out.printf("After %.0f hours: %.2f mg\n", hours, output);
        }
        
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: [1] Please don't provide complete working code for homework questions. And doubly so in this case because the OP's question was _"**the input/output never runs on Netbeans...What am I doing wrong?**"_, so there was absolutely no need to provide a complete working example for their assignment. [2] See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/334823#334823).